# Verify character of string c#

Tags: c#, string

I need to get postal code (like this xx-xxx). I tried to get third character is '-', but it doesn't work. It's console application. Code:

```
static string GetPostalCode(ref Osoba p)
{
   while (true)
   {
      Console.Write("Postal code (xx-xxx): ");
      string postalcode = Console.ReadLine();
      if (postalcode.Length == 7 && postalcode[2] == '-')
      {
         return postalcode;
      }
      else Console.WriteLine("Correct postal code (xx-xxx)");
   }
}
```

Comment: You seem to have a typo in your code: The length of `xx-xxx` is 6, not 7.

Comment: *"it doesn't work"* is not a problem description.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest to use a regular expression in this case:

```
static string GetPostalCode(ref Osoba p)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.Write("Postal code (xx-xxx): ");
            string postalcode = Console.ReadLine();
    
            var pattern = new Regex(@"^\d{2}-\d{3}$");
            if (pattern.IsMatch(postalcode))
            {
                return postalcode;
            }
            else Console.WriteLine("Correct postal code (xx-xxx)");
        }
    }
```